# Route duplex traffic between 2 network cards on same server in Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, rras

I have windows server 2012 R2 with 2 network cards, one connected to a private network(lets say 192.168.1.1) and another one to my work network(for example 192.168.2.1). Now I want to connect this 2 networks and use server as a router.

I have installed RRAS and enabled custom configuration for 'LAN routing' and 'LAN'. Now my problem is:

*If I setup my public network as NAT*, then computers on my private network can reach my public network with ease **but computers and my public network (either with correct entry in route table) can't reach my private network**.

*An if I disable NAT on my public network*, then computers on my private network can't reach my public network **unless they have an entry in their routing table for m private network(192.168.1.XXX)**.

I want a solution that:

1) Computers from my public network can see my private network(after adding an entry to to routing table).

2) Computers on my private network can see my public network without requiring any change in the computers of public network.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need NAT? if not leave it turned off.
Are the computers on your private network using their side of the router as their Default gateway? if no then configure them to do so.
the computers on your public network, what is their default gateway? go to that gateway (router) and add a route that points at your private network Or add a static route to each computer on the public network that points at your private network.

If you need NAT then configure it and then enable port forwarding. all traffic to you private network should be sent to the NAT servers public IP, again you might need to setup routes on your public network to get that tp work.

if your existing routers support RIP then you could also take advantage of that to swap routing information.